# How can I tell PHPStorm to find references to rewritten URLS?

Tags: reference, phpstorm, file-rename

I wanted to rename one of my files, **mypage.php** into **myprofile.php**, but PHPStorm does not find any file references.

In the code, mypage.php is referenced without the file extension. For example:

```
<a href='../user/mypage/'>
```

So it has to look for **mypage**, not mypage.php and rename it **myprofile**, without file extension.

How can I tell the program to do this?

Comment: It cannot do that -- as you have said file name does not match actual URL reference. You have to use `Replace in Path` for that (or just `Replace` if it's in specific/current file only).

Comment: Replace in path works very well, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE cannot do that because (as you have mentioned yourself) the file name does not match actual URL reference.

Your only option here is to use ordinary Find & Replace functionality, e.g. **Replace in Path** to find all occurrences of `/user/mypage/` and replace them into `/user/myprofile/` in all files in a project (note; you can limit the scope for this action to a specific folder or custom scope -- check docs)